# Doing a nested query in a fairly well-planned Rails app, not sure how to optimize query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a user model. For a given user, I want to know if this user has solved one of the admin's questions (admin is also a user, I have the admin user available at all times as admin_user).

Solution belongs_to Question. Question belongs_to User. User has_many solutions.

For a given user, I want to know if

```
Solution[0].question.user.id = admin_user.id or
Solution[1].question.user.id = admin_user.id or
...
Solution[Solution.all.size - 1].question.user.id = admin_user.id
```

I.e. has the current user solved any questions posted by the admin_user.

I can do a nested includes, but after I get all the solutions + relevant data for a given user, I feel like I'll be doing a very expensive loop to determine whether the user has solved any questions for the admin_user.

Any thoughts on how best to write this query?

Thanks!
Ringo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this could solve your problem more efficiently.

```
admin_question_ids = admin_user.questions.map(&:id)
question_ids_answered_by_user = current_user.solutions.map(&:question_id)

has_answered_admin_question = question_ids_answered_by_user.any? do |question_id|
    admin_question_ids.include?(question_id)
end
```